# Can Chell die in the credit sequence?

Tags: portal-2, speedrun

The official speedrunnning rules from [speedrun.com for Portal 2](https://www.speedrun.com/Portal_2) say:

> Timing starts when you gain control of Chell (crosshair appearing) and ends on when the moon is hit (regardless of whether you die in the credits)

I haven't been able to find out what that parenthetical of "regardless of whether you die in the credits" means. Searching online gives me obviously-fake alternate endings, with nothing that looks like it's in the real game (some have claims that they were endings considered in development, but even if I believe that they don't seem to be in the released version).

What is that sentence referring to, and how do you trigger it? Is it possible to have Chell die at the end of Portal 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Massive Spoiler Warning**

**TL;DR: There is no way to die without using console commands. The line in speedrun.com seems to come from theories, people theorize that Chell dies at the end of Portal 2, thanks to the four turrets that appear at the end, and that the turret choir never happened**

After spending some time in the final room, the only thing that happens, is that Glados and Wheatley continue telling you to press/don't press the button. After a while their voice lines stop and Wheatley just looks at the player. You can spend a long amount of time in the room and nothing happens (except for the random debree that sometimes appears and then disappears

[image: Wheatley Tracking You]

Nothing happens until enter the room to press the stalemate button.

[image: The stalemate room]

Entering the room immediately activates Wheatley's "death trap" and starts a cutscene where you pick up the portal gun and aim it the moon. Similar to the before entering the stalemate room, you can spend an infinite amount of time here. You can also move your mouse around to look around the room although you can't move.

[image: Sup Wheatley]

Firing your portal at the moon leads to a cutscene happening where the only thing you can do is scroll your mouse wheel to zoom in.

[image: Zoomed in]

Glados saves you, and the only thing you can do is zoom in an out during the cutscene. Even as the elevator moves up you can do nothing except use your mouse wheel to zoom in.

Then after a while you lose total control of the mouse wheel as the four horsemen of death stare at you and begin to sing along with the rest of the turret choir.

[image: Horsemen of Death]

After that the end credit song starts playing.

**Conclusion: There is no way to die without using console commands. The line in speedrun.com seems to come from theories, people theorize that Chell dies at the end of Portal 2, thanks to the four horsemen of death, and that the turret choir never happened**

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. How would the plot of the game change the timing of a speedrun?

Comment: The question isn't about the timing of a speedrun, it's about if it's possible to have Chell die at the end of the game. I use the different locations available at the ending as evidence that death in the final moments of the game is not possible once the stalemate button room is shown.

Comment: No, the question is very much about the rules of a speedrun. Lore doesn't matter in the slightest here.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I strongly disagree. The sentence in question in the rules of the speedrun could be a joking reference to the lore theories.

Comment: My question was inspired by the speedrun rules but is about the *mechanics* of the game, not the lore or the speedrun itself.  It makes sense if there were theories about this happening given the turrets at the end, even if there hasnʼt been a way discovered to actually get there.

Comment: Generally rules will often explicitly permit given actions/situations to clarify runs involving them are valid, even if it's found these actions are simply unoptimal and lose time vs runs without them (because who knows, maybe a better strategy using them will be developed?) - here we have this taken to the extreme, permitting an action that would be between extremely difficult and impossible - and completely pointless on top of that. It doesn't do any harm, except maybe baffling some people.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. While yes if you cheat and type in the command

```
sv_cheats 1
kill
```

there is no way to do it legit though

Comment: What happens when you die during the credits? Does the game skip ahead to the end?